# Sending a union from Arduino via serial communication and parsing it in python

Tags: serial, code-review, python

I want to send a union from Arduino to a python script running on a pc, and I want to parse the received union. I have read lots of topics online but I am stuck on how to do it in the most efficient way.
Specifically, the union contains a struct of a string containing a sensor name, and a 32 bit integer containing a sensor value.
I use the union as I understood is one of the best ways to deal with binary struct data as the ones I want to send.

Here my Arduino code

```cpp
int32_t analog_input0 = 0;

// Variables to send data
struct serial_message {
  char sensor_name[20]; 
  uint32_t sensor_value;   
};

union serial_message_union {
   serial_message ser_msg;
   uint8_t serial_message_bytes[sizeof(ser_msg)];
};

union serial_message_union ser_msg_u;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  analog_input0 = analogRead(0);
  strcpy(ser_msg_u.ser_msg.sensor_name, "analog_input0");
  ser_msg_u.ser_msg.sensor_value = 100;
  Serial.write(ser_msg_u.serial_message_bytes, sizeof(ser_msg_u.ser_msg));
}
```

Here my python code:

```cpp
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1225061', 115200, timeout = 2) 

while True:
    if(ser.in_waiting > 24): #I set 24 because the message is composed by 20 char + 4 bytes for the uint32_t value
        incoming_data = ser.read(24)
        print('Incoming data: "{}" '.format(incoming_data))

# Here I want to parse the incoming data, where the first 
# 20 bytes are the sensor name and the last 4 bytes are the sensor value
```

Can anyone suggest how can I proceed? Do you see any error/bad software practice so far in my code?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: First question: is my code correct so far? Second question: how can I proceed from there? Once I received the data in the variable incoming_data (assuming that I am doing it right) how can I parse it in the way that allows me to have a variable containing the first 20 bytes and a second variable containing the last 4 bytes?

Comment: Try your code and then let us know what's the issue you had faced with clear definition of issue.

Comment: Why are you using a union? Why not just cast serial_message to uint8_t?

Comment: `if(ser.in_waiting > 24):` - don't you mean >= 24?

Comment: thanks, yes, it is >= 24. Could you please give me an example with code about what you intend when using the casting to uint8_t?